# Corona SDK Application exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus Error: 10. Device Crash

Tags: ios, mobile, lua, segmentation-fault, coronasdk

I have an application that works fine in the Corona Simulator, but crashes on the device itself, and it returns the following error in the iOS device console:

```
Mar 20 22:56:26 tmacs-iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:HappyShaker[0x9cf9]' exited abnormally with signal 10: Bus error: 10
Mar 20 22:56:26 tmacs-iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: BKSendGSEvent ERROR sending event type 23: (ipc/send) invalid destination port (0x10000003)
```

From my research I have found that this error is caused by these two issues:

> 1. Accessing memory that doesn't exist
> 2. Accessing memory that isn't aligned on a 4 or 8 byte boundary

By the way Corona operates, it is most likely the first reason.

As I was debugging I found out something that narrows down the search for the problem.

This code stated below causes the application to crash.  It's a button that starts the physics, sets its scale, adds the physics objects, starts the timer, and removes the button after its pressed. It sort of initializes the physics.

```
local playButton = nil
local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    if "ended" == event.phase then
        physics.start()
        physics.setScale(60)
        physics.addBody( red, "dynamic",redBody )
        physics.addBody( borderTop, "static", borderBodyElement )
        physics.addBody( borderBottom, "static", borderBodyElement )
        physics.addBody( borderLeft, "static", borderBodyElement )
        physics.addBody( borderRight, "static", borderBodyElement )
        timer.performWithDelay(1000, fn_counter, number)
        playButton:removeSelf()
        playButton = nil
    end
    return true
end
playButton = widget.newButton {
    left = _W/2-53,
    top = 400,
    width = 105,
    height = 39,
    defaultFile = "start.png",
    overFile = "start_pressed.png",
    label = "",
    onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
}
playButton.isActive = true
group:insert(playButton)
```

When I comment out the button widget part of the code, it works just fine and doesn't crash.  The part that is commented out is stated in the code below.

```
    -- local playButton = nil
 --     local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    --  if "ended" == event.phase then
            physics.start()
            physics.setScale(60)
            physics.addBody( red, "dynamic",redBody )
            physics.addBody( borderTop, "static", borderBodyElement )
            physics.addBody( borderBottom, "static", borderBodyElement )
            physics.addBody( borderLeft, "static", borderBodyElement )
            physics.addBody( borderRight, "static", borderBodyElement )
            timer.performWithDelay(1000, fn_counter, number)
    --      playButton:removeSelf()
    --      playButton = nil
    --  end
    --  return true
    -- end
    -- playButton = widget.newButton {
    --  left = _W/2-53,
    --  top = 400,
    --  width = 105,
    --  height = 39,
    --  defaultFile = "start.png",
    --  overFile = "start_pressed.png",
    --  label = "",
    --  onEvent = handleButtonEvent,
    -- }
    -- playButton.isActive = true
    -- group:insert(playButton)
```

Has anyone had this issue before with the button widgets?

I should also mention that this code is sitting in the createScene() function for storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.  It had to do with physics.start() being inside of the listener function. I made the following adjustments:

```
physics.start()
physics.setScale( 60 )
physics.addBody( borderTop, "static", borderBodyElement )
physics.addBody( borderBottom, "static", borderBodyElement )
physics.addBody( borderLeft, "static", borderBodyElement )
physics.addBody( borderRight, "static", borderBodyElement )

-- local startButton = nil
local function handleButtonEvent( event )
    if "ended" == event.phase then

        physics.addBody( red, "dynamic",redBody )
        timer.performWithDelay(1000, fn_counter, number)
        startButton:removeSelf()
        startButton = nil
    end
    return true
end
```

By placing the physics.start() function outside of the listener event function made it work.  However, I'm still confused as to why this would cause a segmentation fault.  Could someone explain that to me?